# How to declare a functions on Shortcut Keys

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm creating a library system with `Toolbars` and `Menubars`. I've declared each property of `toolStripButton` with a function of `CheckOnClick` and declare an event of `CheckedChanged` 
with a syntax of

```
if(toolStripButton.Checked == true)
  toolStripButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.PICTURE));
else
  toolStripButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.DEFAULTPICTURE));
```

so that when i ever i click the `toolStripButton` their image will change. each of `toolStripButton` has a `Shortcut Key` coming from `Menubars` like F1, F2, F3, F4
now my question is how can i create a function that when ever i press the `Shortcut Keys` of each `toolStripButton` it will declared the same function of `Click event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i create a function that when ever i press the Shortcut Keys of each toolStripButton it will declared the same function of Click event

In thje handler for the event your using to trap the keys, call the .PerformClick method of the appropriate toolstripbutton

Comment: sir i look at the properties of my `Toolstripmenuitem` but there are no previewkeydown event ther

Comment: how can i call the perform click method i'm newbie at create a class rather than using the encapsulated methods

Comment: Back again.  Been a while since I used toolstrips and menustrips.  Had to refresh my memory.  While my answer may work there is a niftier way.  The toolstrip button are supposed to be shortcuts for a menustrip item.  To set up a shortcut key for the menustrip item just set it's shortcutkey property.  Since both the button and the menuitem cause the same click event the shortcutkey will too.